# How to show a static image in google maps?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Basically, I want to show a crosshairs in the middle of my map that stays in the center as the user pans around.

This is exactly what I'm talking about, except this example is kind of poorly implemented...it's very slow and jumpy when you pan fast.

http://www.daftlogic.com/sandbox-google-maps-centre-crosshairs.htm

Does anyone have any ideas for ways to implement this with the v3 maps api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By far the smoothest method I've seen uses a KML file. [This is the original](http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&hl=en&q=http://kmlscribe.googlepages.com/SamplesInMaps.kml&ie=UTF8&ll=36.879621,-53.4375&spn=103.772916,208.476563&z=2&om=1).

I stripped the KML to the bare minimum:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
      <ScreenOverlay>
        <Icon>
          <href>http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/crosshairs.png</href>
        </Icon>
        <overlayXY x="0.5" y="0.5" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction"/>
        <screenXY x="0.5" y="0.5" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction"/>
        <rotationXY x="0.5" y="0.5" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction"/>
        <size x="0" y="0" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels"/>
      </ScreenOverlay>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

In the maps code all you need to do is set the KML Layer with option `preserveViewport=true`. Note that if you're testing locally the KML file still has to be uploaded to a public location.

```
  var crosshairLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer( 
      'http://freezoo.alwaysdata.net/justcrosshair2.kml', 
      {preserveViewport: true});

    crosshairLayer.setMap(map);
```

JSFiddle 
[style 1](http://jsfiddle.net/zBA3d/) 
[style 2](http://jsfiddle.net/zBA3d/1/)

(They're two separate icons in two KML files.)

Comment: Will this work in a mobile app? I'm using PhoneGap with jQuery Mobile. Any experience in that direction?

Comment: (Also the style 2 fiddle is broken, fyi)

Comment: I have 3 hours of experience trying to get Hello World on the Android emulator :) Before spending too much time make sure a phone/emulator can load the [sample KML (click here)](http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&hl=en&q=http://kmlscribe.googlepages.com/SamplesInMaps.kml&ie=UTF8&ll=36.879621,-53.4375&spn=103.772916,208.476563&z=2&om=1) just like a regular browser. Note that the crosshairs are hard to see in both the sample and Style 2, at that zoom it's really only visible over the ocean. All I did was change the icon image link. It should be working, maybe just taking long to load.